# Cannot find record in database in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I'm trying to create a user login controller

Inside my controller i have statements as

```
user = UserDetail.find_by user_name: params[ :uname ]

if user.nil?

  session[ :message ] = "User doesn't exist"
  redirect_to :back

else

  # if username and password matches then fill details
  if user.user_name == params[ :uname ] && user.password == params[ :pwd ]

    session[ :uname ] = user.user_name
    redirect_to "/expense_details/fill_expense.html"

  else

    session[ :message ] = "wrong password"
    redirect_to :back

  end

end
```

when i am trying this in web browser after `$ rails s`
the "user"  variable is getting populated and giving login successful for username="nilay"
password="nilay123"

But in my rspec "user" variable is not getting populated and remaining nil

my controller spec has statements as follows to validate login

```
it "should redirect to main page with a failure notice as wrong password" do

  params = {
            :uname => 'nilay', 
            :pwd => 'abcdasgdgda'
           }

  post :match_user, params
    #expect(session[:uname]).to eq("manoj12")
    expect(session[:message]).to eq("wrong password")

end


it "should redirect to expense filling page after successful login" do

  params = {
            :uname => "nilay", 
            :pwd => "nilay123", 
           }

  post :match_user, params

  expect(session[:uname]).to eq(params[:uname])

  end
end
```

i am getting the failure message as

Failures:

```
  1) UserLoginController should redirect to main page with a failure notice as wrong password
     Failure/Error: expect(session[:message]).to eq("wrong password")

       expected: "wrong password"
            got: "User doesn't exist"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/user_login_controller_spec.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UserLoginController should redirect to expense filling page after successful login
     Failure/Error: expect(session[:uname]).to eq(params[:uname])

       expected: "nilay"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/user_login_controller_spec.rb:92:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

please let me know how can i achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your tests run in the test environment, while the server starts in the development environment by default. The two environments use two different databases. It sounds like you've created the user with name "nilay" in the dev database but not in the test one.

The simplest solution is to create the user in your test db by including a `before` block in your spec, which will execute before any of the examples. e.g.

```
RSpec.describe ... do
  before(:each) { UserDetail.create(uname: 'nilay', ... ) }

  it 'should redirect to main...' do

  it 'should redirect to expense ...' do
end
```